# How to sort filtered object in dropdown options in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting

In a json object i filtered duplicate product and get array for creating dropdone for search.

```
$scope.value =[{"Product":"Table","Country":"United States","id":"17619"},{"Product":"Chair","Country":"Pakistan","id":"17618"},{"Product":"Keyboard","Country":"Pakistan","id":"17617"},{"Product":"Chair","Country":"Pakistan","id":"17615"}]
```

I filtered duplicate products and get array by this method

```
$scope.getProduct = function(){return ($scope.values || []).map(function(w){return w.Product;}).filter(function(w,idx,arr){return arr.indexOf(w)===idx;});};
```

it return Table, Char, Keyboard as array. which i used in dorpdonw by getProduct() function in this way

```
<select ng-model="product"><option ng-repeat="p in getProduct()" ng-model="filter[p]">{{p}}</option></select>
```

But i want output in sorted form like Char,Keyboard,Table.
How can i sort array return by getProduct()

Comment: what is `ng-model="filter[p]"` in `option`? you already have a model tagged to your `select` with `ng-model="product"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use orderBy filter of angularjs to achieve that.

```
<select ng-model="product"><option ng-repeat="p in getProduct() | orderBy" ng-model="filter[p]">{{p}}</option></select>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/dCrvfd9V5vDIkdv45OT3?p=preview)**

Comment: @Deepak3301086 I'm glad I could help.